# Moving from Nexus 2 to Nexus 3

Tags: nexus

I have tried to find other resources online about how to move things from a Nexus 2.x repository to a Nexus 3.x repository, but came up short.

Can someone who has done this before or might know how to do so please give some sort of guidance of how to do this?

There are guides on moving from one Nexus repository to another one in the same version, but nothing about moving to a new version.

Comment: A detailed documentation now exists here : https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/217967608-How-to-Upgrade-to-Nexus-Repository-Manager-3

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade from Nexus 2 to 3 is coming in the next release (3.1) which will be out this summer.  This will allow moving configuration and repositories from Nexus 2 to Nexus 3.